# UWP InvokeCommandAction on TextBox inside ListView MVVM

Tags: xaml, mvvm, data-binding, win-universal-app, template10

i have a problem to bind a command in a usercontrol included in a view.

UserControl.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SoldItemDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:SoldItem">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         ...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         ...
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Bind q}">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.QChanged, ElementName=SoldRows}" CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
...
<ListView x:Name="SoldRows"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SoldItemsList , Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoldItemDataTemplate}">
...
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"></vm:MainPageViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>
...
<controls:UserControl Grid.Row="1"></controls:UserControl>
...
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
...
private DelegateCommand<object> _QSoldChanged;
...
public DelegateCommand<object> QSoldChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (_QSoldChanged == null)
            {
                _QSoldChanged = new DelegateCommand<object>((object par) =>
                {
                    ...
                });
            }

            return _QSoldChanged;
        }
    }
```

So, i'd like to call QSoldChanged, on TextChanged event, but nothing happens. What am i missing? Is that the right way to set command in this case?
If you need more just ask!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem is with x:Bind  of textbox . It's mode is One way. So text changes doesn't reflect on view model. Change it to Binding. hope it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with x:Bind of textbox . It's mode is One way. So text changes doesn't reflect on view model. Change it to Binding. 
 And this also might be causing problem

{x:Bind} does not use the DataContext as a default source—instead, it uses the page or user control itself. So it will look in the code-behind of your page or user control for properties, fields, and methods. To expose your view model to {x:Bind}, you will typically want to add new fields or properties to the code behind for your page or user control.
 Refer this link [x:Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)

hope it works